# Can we customize CCAVENUE payment page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, ccavenue

Can we customize CCAVENUE payment page where??is that possible?? I'm using INDIPAY package in laravel 5.3.

Please check attached Image for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. These pages are hosted by the payment processor and not in your application. All the package does is redirect to the payment processor with the appropriate payment data from your application. Unless the payment processor allows for customization of their payment page, this cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

CCAvenue gives you option to stylize few sections by going to Settings > Look & Feel.